# What's falling off the Shenzhou/Long March stack?

Tags: launch, long-march, shenzhou

Watching the launch of the Shenzhou-11 mission on a Long March 2F, I noticed a number of items falling off the exterior of the rocket. I'm used to seeing chunks of ice sheet coming off of cryogenic launchers, but Long March uses non-cryogenic hypergolic fuels, and the pieces were squared-off, clearly manufactured items. There were quite a few of them - at least 10 coming off the launcher in the first 20 seconds of flight. Here are a few screenshots showing the debris:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

I don't see any similar items coming off in [this video of Shenzhou-9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RTSGTIe-Rk) or [this one of Shenzhou-10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f45YvWGtrDs).

Comment: I know Ariane 4 used thermal insulators during fueling and those are removed during launch (2/3 seconds after ignition).

The pieces on the pictures look like insulation.

More information can be found in the answer here: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/ariane-4-shroud-around-stage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those falling particles seem to be parts of a protective sheet that shields the opening around the interstage lattice between first and second stages.  Only the Long Marches launched from Taiyuan and Jiuquan during colder times of the year have such cover.

The following are a few examples to illustrate the presence and absence of the sheet in different times of the year.

- TanSat (Long March 2D, TSLC, August 2016) [image: Long March 2D in August 2016]
  <sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Cp63O0OWAAAnW8e.jpg))</sub>
- SuperView (Long March 2D, TSLC, December 2016) [image: Long March 2D in December 2016]
  <sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/GJ1-2-Launch-1-1024x683.jpg))</sub>
- Tiangong-2 (Long March 2F, JSLC, September 2016) [image: Long March 2F in September 2016]
  <sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/05-TG02Launch-1-1024x682.jpg))</sub>
- Shenzhou-11 (Long March 2F, JSLC, October 2016) [image: Long March 2F in October 2016]
  <sub>(source: [spaceflight101.com](https://spaceflight101.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/SZ11-Liftoff-Xinhua-5.jpg))</sub>

EDIT:

- News reports suggest that those are [insulation sheets](http://www.china.com.cn/news/space/2012-11/23/content_27203909.htm) that kept the rocket warm against cold winter.

Comment: This seems plausible; do you have any citations or further information?

Comment: @RussellBorogove The parts before the edit are primarily my observations. [This](http://www.china.com.cn/news/space/2012-11/23/content_27203909.htm) is the best source I can find so far. Unfortunately, it is in Chinese.

Comment: Not sure on this - saw it on 23/8/20 launch of a LM 2D, which is in Chinese summer.

Comment: @throx [Gaofen-9-05 has its own insulation requirement and the fairing has its own insulation sheet](https://n.eastday.com/news/1598152053021412). The interstage insulation, as the question is asked, is notably absent.