# What are the falling parts in this ISRO rocket launch?

Tags: launch, rockets, isro, launch-vehicle, pslv

ISRO launched IRNSS-1I satellite yesterday using its versatile PSLV-XL.

In the launch video (from 00:35 to 00:40), within five seconds of the launch, many large parts of the rocket are seen to be falling off:

What are those parts and why don't they pose any danger to the rocket?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18657/whats-falling-off-the-shenzhou-long-march-stack?rq=1

Comment: A closer view: 0:12-0:14 in this [video](https://www.space.com/india-pslv-launch-three-satellites-june-30) of the 2022 June 30 launch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to this article, those are insulation panels](https://spaceflightnow.com/2018/04/11/isro-launches-for-second-time-in-two-weeks/), and they're simply lightweight enough to not damage the rocket at the relatively low speeds it's moving in the initial seconds of flight.

The insulation keeps the upper-stage liquid propellants from boiling or freezing as the ambient temperature changes -- the oxidizer, [N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinitrogen_tetroxide), in particular, is liquid between -11C and 21C at ambient pressure, although it's pressurized in the tank, so boiling is limited. The [UDMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsymmetrical_dimethylhydrazine) fuel remains liquid over a much wider range.

In some other rocket launches, you'll see more irregular pieces falling off at launch; those are ice chunks, condensed and frozen from water vapor in the air against cryogenic propellant tanks (liquid oxygen, liquid hydrogen, etc). PSLV, however, uses non-cryogenic hypergolic propellants, so it doesn't condense ice.